# Ionic Framework : How to change states having dynamic URL?

Tags: ionic-framework

```
 $stateProvider.
  state('steps', {
        url: '/steplist/:stepList/:startStepId/:endStepId',
        templateUrl: 'views/step.html',
        controller: 'StepsCtrl'
  });
```

---

I have the state 'steps' and it's url has :steplist , :startStepId and :endStepId dynamically set. So how do I set these values from the controller using $state.go() function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options]);`

The second parameter of `$state.go()` is an object containing the state parameters. See [ui-router project wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#user-content-state-1) for more details.

```
$state.go('steps', { stepList: 1, startStepId: 2, endStepId: 3});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Currently I am sending JSON array as the params. And I get this error:

[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams

Comment: you have to inject $routeParams in your controller.

Comment: That's probably on your controller. You're injecting `$routeParams`, which is ng-route parameter.  Ionic uses ui-router which injects `$stateParams`.

Comment: Thank you everybody. $stateParams worked happily. I know i am a noob. ^_^